# How to Create dynamic Excel sheet and download to client location

Tags: asp.net

Hi I want to fill the database table in dynamically created Excel sheet through save dialog

Answer (score 0):

[How to Export Data to Excel from an ASP.NET Application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erikaehrli/archive/2009/01/30/how-to-export-data-to-excel-from-an-asp-net-application-avoid-the-file-format-differ-prompt.aspx)